# margins package - help in R

Tags: r, regression, glm

I estimated a probit model by using the `glm` function.
From the package `lmtest` is very easy to compute clustered standard errors by using the `coeftest` function.

To compute the average marginal effect, I type: `AME=margins(model1, variables = c("x", "y"))`.

How can I compute the clustered errors of `AME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margins` package is now in “maintenance mode”, which means that it is not being actively developed. I recommend you use the `marginaleffects` package instead, which was designed as a successor (disclaimer: I am the author): https://marginaleffects.com

You can use clustered standard errors by specifying a one-sided formula in the `vcov` argument:

```r
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- glm(vs ~ mpg + hp + factor(cyl), data = mtcars, family = binomial)

avg_slopes(mod,
  variables = c("mpg", "hp"),
  vcov = ~cyl)
# 
#  Term Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)    S    2.5 %   97.5 %
#   hp  -0.00282   0.000476 -5.937   <0.001 28.4 -0.00376 -0.00189
#   mpg -0.01242   0.015213 -0.817    0.414  1.3 -0.04224  0.01739
# 
# Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high
```

Compare to classical IID standard errors:

```r
avg_slopes(mod, variables = c("mpg", "hp"))
# 
#  Term Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 %  97.5 %
#   hp  -0.00282    0.00228 -1.236    0.216 2.2 -0.0073 0.00165
#   mpg -0.01242    0.01681 -0.739    0.460 1.1 -0.0454 0.02053
# 
# Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high
```

See the documentation for `vcov` in `?avg_slopes` for details.

Comment: That's amazing, I was thinking of coming back to Stata, but you just remembered me how good the R community is